# How to secure a script that generates an HTML file from other websites?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a ksh script (Korn Shell Script) that generates a static HTML file from websites. How can I ensure that the output HTML file will not contain any bad `<script>`'s (bad JavaScript)? It's OK to do this:

```
sed 's/<script>//g'
```

But what if the `<script>` is obfuscated?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What's the threat here? How are you using those static HTML files? Also, JavaScript can be embedded in the HTML elements. For example `<a href="#" onclick="alert('alert')"></a>`

Comment: The problem is defining and recognizing 'bad' in context. I'm afraid you've asked a question without an answer. Refine it and add some specifics.

Comment: You may want to consider a way to extract good content since it may be easier to define. Otherwise, you may be able to look at something like noscript which is licensed under GPL to get a better idea of what is 'bad' scripting and how to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trolling web sites.   When you do that - you get whatever content is on the site including scripts.

Modern web sites basically are useless without JS - so I don't see how you can excise the JS and still have functional content unless you're trying to get textual/graphic content for fun and profit....

Without knowing what is the object of this exercise - I would highly recommend loading the content and it's scripts on a test server on a network segment without connectivity to the rest of your network.  Then you can fool around to your heart's content.

Hope this helps.